# Android SDK display images on different devices with different screen resolutions

Tags: android

I have question that is connected to display images on android devices.

I have many png files that I want to display and they have got 1024 x 768 resolution and have text in image. The text in images must be readable - this is important thing. Because png it is bitmap format I understand that the loss of quality is inevitable. Maybe some one can advice me to choose some approach to solve this issue. Maybe I have to choose just devices that can display those images.

All images like this below:

[image]

Comment: It's not a very good practice to put text in an image. If you can remove from picture and put them in android components such as textview, it would be much better

Comment: Yes, but the text has specific symbols especially mathematical formula elements that as I think textview does not support.

Comment: OK, I see the problem better but I do not have ideas..sorry